# Where can I add the validation script?

Tags: php, validation

I wanted to add a validation script in my codes. this is my login code and checklogin code. I wanted to add a validation script inside it, in which part / piece of code should I add the validation script?

this is my login.php

```
<html><head>    
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>        
    <div class="container" id="contain">

      <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="checklogin.php" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2></br></br>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Email<span class="error">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" placeholder="Email address" autofocus="" value=""/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Password<span class="error">*</span></label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="password" placeholder="Password" value=""/>
          </div>
        <p style="text-align:right;"><a href="forgotpwd.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Forgot password?</a></p>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my checklogin.php for checking the database if the user exists.

```
<?php

session_start();
require('connection.php'); 

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$email = stripslashes($email);
$password = stripslashes($password);

$sql = "select * from user_info where email = '$email' and pwd = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error() );

$count = 0;

while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $count++;
}

if ($count == 1) {
     $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "true";
     header("Location: loginSuccess.php");
} else {
     $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "false";
     header("Location: loginFailed.php");
}

?>
```

How and where should I put my validation script? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your javascript validation in the  section.

One of the use of js is that, it is used as the client side validating script.

Just before submitting your form, try to call some javascript function to validate whether username and password is not null. This will reduce the burden on your server from processing the unwanted requests.

Here's [a link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_quick_guide.htm) for the js tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

In your HTML file, do this change :

```
<head>    
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="signin.js"></script>
</head>

----

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="btn_signin">Sign in</button>
```

And in your javascript file :

```
// bind click event of btn_signin for setting the account
$('#btn_signin').click(function(){
    // do the validation and if success, then submit the form, otherwise return false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague but usually the flow is like this:

1. The user arrives at the page and gets the empty form
2. The user fills the form and submits it
3. The server receives the form data and validates it
   3.1 if data is invalid, show form again with errors and filled with submitted data
   3.2 if data is valid, proceed

In code this looks like this:

on login.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // pull this out of the checklogin.php file

if ($_POST['email']){
    // assumed user is trying to login
    // so validate data
    include 'checklogin.php';
}
?>

<html><head>    
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>        
    <div class="container" id="contain">

      <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="login.php" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2></br></br>
        <?php if (isset($errors['login']){ echo $errors['login']; } ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php if (isset($errors['email']){ echo $errors['email']; } ?>
            <label for="">Email<span class="error">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" placeholder="Email address" autofocus="" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>"/>
          </div>
  ... removed for the sake of clarity ...

// note that the form submits to itself and php vars are echoed into the page if they exist
```

on checklogin.php there are several things that can be improved considering that a login should be secure. See php filter functions to validate email, check password length, use PDO instead of mysql_query to avoid sql injections etc. But for now lets do this:

```
if ($count == 1) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "true";
    header("Location: loginSuccess.php");
} else {
    $errors = array();
    $errors['login'] = 'whoops... could not login'; // this var is available for the html in login.php
}
```